# ubuntu crash semingly random during video

Tags: 20.04, video, crash

I've installed Ubuntu 20.04 onto a hardrive on my computer, and I love it. It's gotten to the point I prefer it over windows, (which I use for gaming) but theres this one issue that really doesn't make me look at Ubuntu in a good light.

Every so often, if I'm watching a video, (or more recently just looking at an mpv video), Ubuntu freezes, and plays whatever part of the video I'm on repeatedly a few times. I can't do anything other than just hold down the power button and try and get back all of my lost progress. (The final straw was when it happened in the middle of a blender render)

This has really made me look at Ubuntu as unstable and I can't seem to find a fix for this either, or even prevent it, which makes it more frustrating.

Comment: If you're using Wayland, try switching to Xorg for your display server.  I had some instability issues with Debian and Wayland that were very similar to what you're describing and switching to Xorg fixed it.  At your login screen when you're at the password box, you should see a gear icon in the lower right you can click and select the type of display server you want.  It may just say "Gnome" instead of Wayland, but one option should say something like "Gnome on X".  Select that one.  Everything will be functionally the same, but it'll use the older, yet more stable X.org display server.

Answer (score 1):

System "freezes" are often caused by running too many, too large programs and running out of available memory. Use `free` to see if you have swap space, read `man mkswap swapon fstab` to create some. Swap space must be contiguous. use `mkswap` or `fallocate`, not `dd`. Traditionally, swap space of 1.5 × RAM has been recommended,  but YMMV. If you don't plan to hibernate your system, you can have less than 1.0 × RAM.
Also,
After a "sudden shutdown", aka "system crash", and reboot, or an intentional reboot, the terminal  command `sudo journalctl  -b -1 -e` will show you the end of the previous boot's logs. If there is no hint there, suspect power/ overheating.

Overheating is most likely caused by dust. Power down your system. Unblock your fans and vents, clean out the dust. Ensure air circulation. Dust that coats heat exchangers and chips is a good insulator,  and bad for cooling. Don't disassemble your computer until you have downloaded the manufacturer's  manual, and researched how-to-clean. Make this information available for when your computer isn't (paper, other computer) **Don't use water.**

Read `man journalctl` to see how to extract information from the logs.

You can find how I make use of `journalctl` easier at `https://askubuntu.com/users/25618/waltinator`.

Comment: When you mean "memory" do you mean "ram?"

Comment: "RAM" Is an acronym for "Random Access Memory", so, yes.